# Unable to navigate one of whole URL

Tags: vbscript

Unable to navigate one of whole URL using VBScript example:

htt://www.google.com="GlobalHistory"&customer=guest&password=guest&STARTTIME=2016,01,26,00,00,00&STOPTIME=2016,01,27,00,00,00&POINTSEVERY=15 min&GRAPHTYPE=excel

But it only navigates to its first half like https://www.google.com.

Comment: Please post your actual code.  Judging by the quotes in the URL this is likely a string issue but we need to see what you are doing to tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Like... in other words, there is nothing wrong with that URL (well there is.. it should be `http://` not `htt://`, but whatever). The problem is with your code, but we can't see your code, so we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a few problems.  First, that URL is totally bogus.  It looks like you were trying to hide your domain, which is fine I guess.  Without posting your code, it's hard to be sure what you actually want, but here is an example of a VBScript launching a URL that has spaces in it (I think this is your main issue)

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run """http://www.example.com?parameter=has spaces"""
```